# Do vertex IDs stay the same every time I run osm2po?

Tags: openstreetmap, pgrouting, osm2po

Does anybody knows if vertex (*source, target* columns) in osm2po tables are always the same?

I have my **dr_2po_4pgr** table with routing data and **dr_matrix** with routes already made. In this table I have *source,target,cost* columns. This is for avoid *pgrouting* functions that penalize the performance (I need to make many calls to these functions).

My question is, if when I generate an updated **dr_2po_4pgr** (osm2po routing table) table  with a new osm file should also update my table **dr_matrix** or if *source,target* id's are always the same.

Thanks in advance!!

Pd: excuse my english

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's the nature of osm that everyone can modify things. Hence you cannot rely on IDs.